# Rake: auto-delete intermediate files? (Equivalent of make's .INTERMEDIATE mechanism?)

Tags: ruby, rake, rakefile

With make I can do something like:

```
%.json : %.jsonnet
    jsonnet $< -o $@

JSON_FILES = main.tf.json

.INTERMEDIATE : $(JSON_FILES)

plan : $(JSON_FILES)
    terraform plan
```

With this in place, if I run

```
make plan
```

My file `main.tf.jsonnet` will be compiled to `main.tf.json` (a format the Terraform program can understand), Terraform will run, and after it's finished, the `main.tf.json` file will automatically be deleted.

I'm wondering if there's a similar function in Rake? Take this mostly-similar Rakefile:

```ruby
require 'rake/clean'

rule '.json' => '.jsonnet' do |t|
  sh "jsonnet '#{t.source}' -o '#{t.name}'"
end

JSON_FILES = Dir["**/*.jsonnet"].map{ |f| f.sub(/jsonnet$/, 'json')}
CLEAN.include(JSON_FILES)

desc "See what changes will be made (terraform plan)"
task plan: JSON_FILES do
  sh "terraform plan"
end
```

If I run `rake plan`, it will execute nearly the same as make, but it will leave `main.tf.json` on the filesystem. I've been simply appending `Rake::Task[:clean].execute` to the end of all relevant tasks, but that's a bit hacky. Is there a nicer way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with another kind of gross hack to sort of do what I want...

The rule now looks like this:

```
$needs_clean = false

rule '.json' => '.jsonnet' do |t|
  $needs_clean = true
  sh "jsonnet '#{t.source}' -o '#{t.name}'"
end
```

And the end of the Rakefile has this:

```
at_exit { Rake::Task[:clean].invoke if $needs_clean }
```

I'm not the biggest fan of this solution, but it seems to work so far...